# How can I escape React useEffect infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I wrote a code that receives the api through React Hook and calls the api again in the child component by passing the id when clicking. However, there seems to be a problem in settingState with arrow function in useEffect or onClick of child component.

I would appreciate it if you could give me an answer on how to fix it.

**Users.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import UserInfo from './UserInfo';


function Users() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState(null)
    const [loding, setLoding] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)


    const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null)

    const fetchUsers = async () => {
        try {
            setUsers(null)
            setError(null);
            setLoding(true)

            const respnse = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')

            setUsers(respnse)
        } catch (e) {
            setError(e)
        }
        setLoding(false)
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUsers();
    }, []);

    if (loding) return <div>loading...</div>
    if (error) return <div>error....</div>
    if (!users) return null;

    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                {
                    users.data.map(user =>
                        <li key={user.id} onClick={() => setUserId(user.id)} >
                            {user.username} ({user.name})
                        </li>
                    )
                }
            </ul>
            <button onClick={fetchUsers}>
                reload
            </button>
            {userId && <UserInfo id={userId} />}
        </>
    );
}

export default Users;
```

**UserInfo.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function UserInfo({ id }) {

    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null)

    async function getUsersAPI() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
            setUserInfo(response)
        } catch (e) {

        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getUsersAPI()
    }, [userInfo])


    if (!userInfo) {
        return null;
    }

    const { data } = userInfo

    return (
        <>
            <h2>{data.username}</h2>
            <p>
                <b>email: </b>{data.email}
            </p>
        </>
    );
}

export default UserInfo;
```

Comment: why is `userInfo` in the dependency array for `useEffect`?

Comment: It is implemented so that it can have useinfo information through the api.

If I'm wrong, please give me another answer.

Comment: `getUsersAPI` updates the `userInfo` state, which as a dependency, triggers the `useEffect` hook's callback to again call `getUsersAPI`, thus creating a render loop. When do you *actually* want the effect in the child to run? If I had to guess, it should be the `id` prop that is passed since that is referenced in the `getUsersAPI` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you want `id` to be a `useEffect` dependency instead of `userInfo.`

Otherwise every time `userInfo` changes the effect will run, it will call `getUsersAPI` which in turns sets the value of `userInfo` when axios resolves (thus causing an infinite loop).

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

    function UserInfo({ id }) {
        const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null)
        async function getUsersAPI() {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
                setUserInfo(response)
            } catch (e) {}
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            getUsersAPI()
        }, [id])

        if (!userInfo) {
            return null;
        }

        const { data } = userInfo

        return (
            <>
                <h2>{data.username}</h2>
                <p>
                    <b>email: </b>{data.email}
                </p>
            </>
        );
    }

    export default UserInfo;
```

Answer (score 1):

this problem is due to the fact that you have set `userInfo` as a dependency for `useEffect` dependency array! every time this component renders, useEffect will call your API and it changes the value of userInfo, so you encounter with infinite loop!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the UserInfo.js file.
In these lines:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUsersAPI()
}, [userInfo])
```

You fetch userInfo but then `setUserInfo(response)` again which cause useEffect to run again.

If might want to leave it as:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUsersAPI()
}, [])
```

So the useEffect only run once.
Or you want it to reflect your last userId from props then put userId to the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUsersAPI()
}, [id])
```